State not updating in Atlassian Modal using hooks
I'd like to show a flag (a separate component) on clicking Delete button. But state doesn't get updated, so flag isn't showing up. What might be the cause?
export const Modal: FC<Props> = ({
    (some props)
}) => {
  const onClose = (): void => {
    onCloseProp?.();
  };

  const [flags, setFlags] = React.useState<Array<number>>([]); // State not updating

  const addFlag = () => {
    const newFlagId = flags.length + 1;
    const newFlags = flags.slice();
    newFlags.splice(0, 0, newFlagId);

    setFlags(newFlags);
  };

  const handleDismiss = () => {
    setFlags(flags.slice(1));
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ModalTransition>
        <AtlassianModal
          onClose={onClose}
          width={modalSize?.width}
          height={modalSize?.height}
          shouldCloseOnEscapePress
          shouldCloseOnOverlayClick
          shouldScrollInViewport
          autoFocus={false}
        >
          <ModalHeader>
              <ModalTitle>
                <Heading level="h600">{title}</Heading>
              </ModalTitle>
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>{children}</ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <LeftAlignedButtonWrapper>
              {deleteOptions && (
                  <Button
                      appearance={'danger'}
                      onClick={(e): void => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        addFlag();
                        deleteOptions.callback();
                      }}
                      label={deleteOptions.label}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </Button>
              )}
            </LeftAlignedButtonWrapper>
            <UndoFlag flags={flags} onDismiss={handleDismiss} /> // Flag to show
            ...


Here's the Flag component:
import React from 'react';

import SuccessIcon from '@atlaskit/icon/glyph/check-circle';
import { token } from '@atlaskit/tokens';
import { Box } from '@atlaskit/primitives';
import { AutoDismissFlag, FlagGroup } from '@atlaskit/flag';

interface UndoFlagProps {
    flags: number[];
    onDismiss: () => void;
}

const UndoFlag = ({ flags, onDismiss }: UndoFlagProps) => {
    return (
        <Box>
            <FlagGroup onDismissed={onDismiss}>
                {flags.map((flagId) => {
                    return (
                        <AutoDismissFlag
                            id={flagId}
                            icon={
                                <SuccessIcon
                                    primaryColor={token('color.icon.success')}
                                    label="Success"
                                    size="medium"
                                />
                            }
                            key={flagId}
                            title={`#${flagId} Your changes were saved`}
                            description="I will auto dismiss after 8 seconds."
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </FlagGroup>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default UndoFlag;


I tried passing a true/false flag as a prop to UndoFlag to show what I need and flip it in Modal component. Actually, I need to show a flag on clicking Delete in Modal.
